# Use a value from the previous row in an R data.table calculation

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a new column in a data.table calculated from the current value of one column and the previous of another.  Is it possible to access previous rows?

E.g.:

```
> DT <- data.table(A=1:5, B=1:5*10, C=1:5*100)
> DT
   A  B   C
1: 1 10 100
2: 2 20 200
3: 3 30 300
4: 4 40 400
5: 5 50 500
> DT[, D := C + BPreviousRow] # What is the correct code here?
```

The correct answer should be

```
> DT
   A  B   C   D
1: 1 10 100  NA
2: 2 20 200 210
3: 3 30 300 320
4: 4 40 400 430
5: 5 50 500 540
```

Comment: I usually set a key to my data.tables: ``DT <- data.table(A=..., key = "A")``

Answer (score 116, accepted):

With `shift()` implemented in [v1.9.6](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table), this is quite straightforward.

```
DT[ , D := C + shift(B, 1L, type="lag")]
# or equivalently, in this case,
DT[ , D := C + shift(B)]
```

---

From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 5. New function `shift()` implements fast `lead/lag` of *vector*, *list*, *data.frames* or *data.tables*. It takes a `type` argument which can be either *"lag"* (default) or *"lead"*. It enables very convenient usage along with `:=` or `set()`. For example: `DT[, (cols) := shift(.SD, 1L), by=id]`. Please have a look at `?shift` for more info.

---

See history for previous answers.

Comment: Does that `.N` hold the current row number or something? Sorry to ask here, but I can't seem to find it in the help files...

Comment: @SlowLearner: You might also find `.I` useful, which holds the row indices for the rows in the curren group.

Comment: Use seq_len(.N - 1) instead of 1:(.N-1). This avoids problems  associated with 1:0.

Comment: +1 for the `.SD` example--I was trying to use a `lapply` and getting funky results. this is much simpler.

Comment: Where can I find an updated pdf with all this new information ?
The official 1.9.4 vignettes and webminars don't include it.
And the Rmd 1.9.5 vignettes are not comfortable and don't include it either.

Comment: @Arun , your first solution says "Error in C + shift(B, 1L, type = "lag") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator" in my data.table 1.9.5

Comment: @skan, update to the latest commit of data.table... Made changes yesterday. If using devel, better to **watch** the project on GitHub

Comment: Note - for me at least - using shift was much slower that using 'slicing' with -N - see timings here (for a data.table of 1,5 mio. rows) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372627/how-to-construct-an-edgeliste-from-a-list-of-visited-places-effectively

Answer (score 57):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
mutate(DT, D = lag(B) + C)
```

Which gives:

```
#   A  B   C   D
#1: 1 10 100  NA
#2: 2 20 200 210
#3: 3 30 300 320
#4: 4 40 400 430
#5: 5 50 500 540
```

Answer (score 24):

Several folks have answered the specific question.  See the code below for a general purpose function that I use in situations like this that may be helpful.  Rather than just getting the prior row, you can go as many rows in the "past" or "future" as you'd like.

```
rowShift <- function(x, shiftLen = 1L) {
  r <- (1L + shiftLen):(length(x) + shiftLen)
  r[r<1] <- NA
  return(x[r])
}

# Create column D by adding column C and the value from the previous row of column B:
DT[, D := C + rowShift(B,-1)]

# Get the Old Faithul eruption length from two events ago, and three events in the future:
as.data.table(faithful)[1:5,list(eruptLengthCurrent=eruptions,
                                 eruptLengthTwoPrior=rowShift(eruptions,-2), 
                                 eruptLengthThreeFuture=rowShift(eruptions,3))]
##   eruptLengthCurrent eruptLengthTwoPrior eruptLengthThreeFuture
##1:              3.600                  NA                  2.283
##2:              1.800                  NA                  4.533
##3:              3.333               3.600                     NA
##4:              2.283               1.800                     NA
##5:              4.533               3.333                     NA
```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, I'm annoyed that I've already upvoted the other answers because this is a far more general answer.  In fact, I'm going to use it in my geneorama package (if you don't mind).

Comment: Sure, go for it.  I was hoping to get some free time and submit it as a pull request to the `data.table` package, but alas...

Comment: A similar function called `shift` has been added to `data.table` as of version 1.9.5.  See the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14689467/1344789) from @Arun.

Answer (score 13):

Based on @Steve Lianoglou 's comment above, why not just:

```
DT[, D:= C + c(NA, B[.I - 1]) ]
#    A  B   C   D
# 1: 1 10 100  NA
# 2: 2 20 200 210
# 3: 3 30 300 320
# 4: 4 40 400 430
# 5: 5 50 500 540
```

And avoid using `seq_len` or `head` or any other function.

Comment: Nice - however this would not work if you wanted to find the previous within a group.

Comment: @Matthew you are right. If subsetting by group I would replace `.I` with `seq_len(.N)`

Answer (score 9):

Following Arun's solution, a similar results can be obtained without referring to to `.N`

```
> DT[, D := C + c(NA, head(B, -1))][]
   A  B   C   D
1: 1 10 100  NA
2: 2 20 200 210
3: 3 30 300 320
4: 4 40 400 430
5: 5 50 500 540
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer one method to another?  Or is it simply an aesthetic difference?

Comment: I think that in this scenario (i.e. where `.N` is readily available) it is mostly aesthetic choice. I am not aware of any important difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my intuitive solution:

```
#create data frame
df <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=seq(10,50,10), C=seq(100,500, 100))`
#subtract the shift from num rows
shift  <- 1 #in this case the shift is 1
invshift <- nrow(df) - shift
#Now create the new column
df$D <- c(NA, head(df$B, invshift)+tail(df$C, invshift))`
```

Here `invshift`, the number of rows minus 1, is 4. `nrow(df)` provides you with the number of rows in a data frame or in a vector. Similarly, if you want to take still earlier values, subtract from nrow 2, 3, ...etc, and also put NA's accordingly at the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

it can be done in a loop.

```
# Create the column D
DT$D <- 0
# for every row in DT
for (i in 1:length(DT$A)) {
  if(i==1) {
    #using NA at first line
    DT[i,4] <- NA
  } else {
    #D = C + BPreviousRow
    DT[i,4] <- DT[i,3] + DT[(i-1), 2]   
  }
}
```

Using a for, you can even use the previous value of the row of this new column  `DT[(i-1), 4]`