# Finding all overlaps in one iteration of foverlap in R's data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to merge a bunch of overlapping time periods in R using a data.table. I've got a call to foverlap of the table on itself, which is efficient enough.

My problem is such: say period A overlaps period B, and B overlaps period C, but A does not overlap C. In that case A is not grouped with C, and they will eventually have to be merged.

Currently I've got a while loop finding overlaps and merging until no more merges occur, but that's not exactly scalable. One solution I can see is applying the indices of the groups recursively to itself until it stabilises, but that still looks to need a loop, and I want a completely vectorised solution.

```
dt = data.table(start = c(1,2,4,6,8,10),
                end   = c(2,3,6,8,10,12))
setkeyv(dt,c("start","end"))

f = foverlaps(dt,
              dt,
              type="any",
              mult="first",
              which="TRUE")

#Needs to return [1,1,3,3,3,3]
print(f)
#1 1 3 3 4 5
print(f[f])
#1 1 3 3 3 4
print(f[f][f])
#1 1 3 3 3 3
```

Can anyone help me with some ideas on vectorising this procedure?

Edit with IDs:

```
dt = data.table(id = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'),
                eventStart = c(1,2,4,6,8,10,11,15),
                eventEnd   = c(2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16))
setkeyv(dt,c("id","eventStart","eventEnd"))

f = foverlaps(dt,
              dt,
              type="any",
              mult="first",
              which="TRUE")

#Needs to return [1 1 3 3 3 6 6 8] or similar
```

Comment: Relevant, though rather complex - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574775/is-it-possible-to-use-the-r-data-table-function-foverlaps-to-find-the-intersecti or maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006269/how-to-combine-intervals-data-into-fewer-intervals-in-r

Comment: "#Needs to return [1,1,3,3,3]" -- shouldn't it have a length of six? Anyway, if your intervals are structured like this example where start >= lag(end), then `dt[, cumsum(start-shift(end, fill=0) > 0)]` would seem to work.

Comment: @Frank thanks for that, I had inadvertently copied an earlier version.

Comment: @Frank thanks that is a fantastic solution, so short! Unfortunately my dataset is just a tiny bit freakier than the example, and some intervals are completely subsumed by others, and this seems to fall over a bit under those conditions :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IRanges` package on Bioconductor from which `data.table`'s `foverlaps()` was inspired has some handy functions for questions like this.

Perhaps, `reduce()` might be the function you are looking for to merge all overlapping periods:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(start = c(1,2,4,6,8,10),
                end   = c(2,3,6,8,10,12))

library(IRanges)
ir <- IRanges(dt$start, dt$end)

ir
```

> ```
> IRanges object with 6 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
>           start       end     width
>       <integer> <integer> <integer>
>   [1]         1         2         2
>   [2]         2         3         2
>   [3]         4         6         3
>   [4]         6         8         3
>   [5]         8        10         3
>   [6]        10        12         3
> ```

```
reduce(ir, min.gapwidth = 0L)
```

> ```
> IRanges object with 2 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
>           start       end     width
>       <integer> <integer> <integer>
>   [1]         1         3         3
>   [2]         4        12         9
> ```

```
as.data.table(reduce(ir, min.gapwidth = 0L))
```

> ```
>    start end width
> 1:     1   3     3
> 2:     4  12     9
> ```

On Bioconductor, there is a comprehensive [Introduction to `IRanges`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/IRanges/inst/doc/IRangesOverview.pdf) available.

---

**Edit**: The OP has supplied a second sample data set which includes an `id` column and is asking if `IRanges` has support for joining intervals by `id`.

Adding data to `IRanges` seems to specialize quickly into the area of genome research which is *terra incognita* to me. However, I've found the following approach using `IRanges`:

#### Grouping with `IRanges`

```
library(data.table)
# 2nd sample data set provided by the OP
dt = data.table(id = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'),
                eventStart = c(1,2,4,6,8,10,11,15),
                eventEnd   = c(2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16))

library(IRanges)
# set names when constructing IRanges object
ir <- IRanges(dt$eventStart, dt$eventEnd, names = dt$id)

lapply(split(ir, names(ir)), reduce, min.gapwidth = 0L)
```

> ```
> $A
> IRanges object with 2 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
>           start       end     width
>       <integer> <integer> <integer>
>   [1]         1         3         3
>   [2]         4        10         7
>
> $B
> IRanges object with 2 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
>           start       end     width
>       <integer> <integer> <integer>
>   [1]        10        14         5
>   [2]        15        16         2
> ```

Converting this back to `data.table` leads to a rather clumsy piece of code:

```
ir <- IRanges(dt$eventStart, dt$eventEnd, names = dt$id)
rbindlist(lapply(split(ir, names(ir)), 
                 function(x) as.data.table(reduce(x, min.gapwidth = 0L))), 
          idcol = "id")
```

> ```
>    id start end width
> 1:  A     1   3     3
> 2:  A     4  10     7
> 3:  B    10  14     5
> 4:  B    15  16     2
> ```

#### Grouping within `data.table`

We can get the same result with a less convoluted code if we group within `data.table` and apply `reduce()` on the single chunks:

```
dt[, as.data.table(reduce(IRanges(eventStart, eventEnd), min.gapwidth = 0L)), id]
```

Comment: Thanks Uwe, that's very helpful. Do you know if IRanges has support for joining intervals by ID (see edit)?