# Balance calculation using value of the previous row

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

Table I have:

```
DT <- data.frame(A=1:5*10, B=1:5*-1)
DT
   A  B
1 10 -1
2 20 -2
3 30 -3
4 40 -4
5 50 -5
```

Table I want:

C=A+B+C(n-1)

```
   A  B  C
1 10 -1  9
2 20 -2 27
3 30 -3 54
4 40 -4 90
5 50 -5 135
```

I have reference below link and try to apply but fail:

[Use a value from the previous row in an R data.table calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689424/use-a-value-from-the-previous-row-in-an-r-data-table-calculation)

```
DT$C<-DT$A+DT$B+shift(DT$C)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am not missing something, this will do the trick:

```
DT <- data.table(A=1:5*10, B=1:5*-1)
DT[, C := cumsum(A + B)]
```

Comment: Good eye! And if it were a dataframe named DF then `DF$C=with(DF, cumsum(A+B))`

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
     mutate(C= cumsum(A+B))
#   A  B   C
#1 10 -1   9
#2 20 -2  27
#3 30 -3  54
#4 40 -4  90
#5 50 -5 135
```