# diff on data.table column

Tags: r, data.table, diff, rollapply

I just want to take difference between rows in a data.table such that dif[n] = value[n] - value[n-1].

I currently try to achive that using `zoo::rollapplyr`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- fread(text = "#
variable    value
xyz 3
xyz 7
xyz 5
abc 9
abc 10
abc 2
")

dt[, dif := zoo::rollapplyr(value, 2, function(x){r <- diff(x,lag = 1)}, align = "right"), by = list(variable)]

#> dt
#>    variable value dif
#> 1:      xyz     3   4
#> 2:      xyz     7  -2
#> 3:      xyz     5   4
#> 4:      abc     9   1
#> 5:      abc    10  -8
#> 6:      abc     2   1
```

But, compared to what I have, the results should be shifted by 1 position, and the first position for each "variable" should be NA, i.e. `dif` should be `c(NA, 4, -2, NA, 1, -8)`. The first value for each "variable should be NA because there is no position n-1. Any idea how I can modify the function to accomplish this?  Would really like to know how I can do this with rollapplyr for the sake of my own understanding.

EDIT 2024: `data.table` prevents the unwanted recycling of the generated `dif` values by failing with this error message:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(dif, zoo::rollapply(value, 2, function(x) { : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 3 in column 'dif'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Comment: what would you want your last value to be? I see that value 5 of dif is -8 form (2 - 8), what would you want where the 1 is?

Comment: The more general question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14689424/ (with the same answer as mtoto's)

Comment: dif should be (NA, 4, -2, NA, 1, -8).  The first value for each "variable should be NA because there is no position n-1.

Comment: Fyi, this is why you should put your desired output into the question itself in the first place, so there's no room for misunderstanding it. It's not too late to edit it in now.

Comment: You can also do 
dt[,c(NA,diff(value)), by = variable]

Comment: @skan, this would be a deepcopy of whole `value`

Answer (score 16):

We could use `shift()`:

```
dt[,diff := value - shift(value), by = variable]
> dt
   variable value diff
1:      xyz     3   NA
2:      xyz     7    4
3:      xyz     5   -2
4:      abc     9   NA
5:      abc    10    1
6:      abc     2   -8
```

Comment: this just shifts the entire column down.  The first value for abc, and xyz should be NA because there is no n-1 value at these positions.  This is the behavior I get when I use all other functions with rollapplyr()

Comment: Thanks.  Much appreciated.  This definitely works and will use it.  I would still really like to understand why I can't use rollapplyr() though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dt[, dif := zoo::rollapplyr(value, 2, function(x){diff(x,lag = 1)}, fill = NA), by = list(variable)]

> dt
   variable value dif
1:      xyz     3  NA
2:      xyz     7   4
3:      xyz     5  -2
4:      abc     9  NA
5:      abc    10   1
6:      abc     2  -8
```

Comment: Since the call to `rollapplyr` changed it would be great to update the answer. From the `rollapplyr` documentation: `na.pad` deprecated. Use `fill = NA` instead of `na.pad = TRUE`.