# Use previously calculated value in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The `x.wanted` in the MWE uses `x.wanted` calculated on the row above and then adds values from actual row. How can that be done in data.table? I thought `shift` was the way, but gives wrong result.

`x.wanted` is a way to separate bars in a plot that have different bar-widths.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
dt <- data.table(x.group=c(rep(1L, 4L), rep(2L, 5L)),
                 x.width=c(2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L),
                 x.sep=c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                 x.wanted=c(1, 5, 9, 14, 2, 6, 10, 16, 21))

dt[, x.try.1:=x.width/2]
dt[, x.try.1:=shift(x=x.try.1, fill=0, type="lag") + x.sep + x.width/2, by=x.group]

p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=x.wanted, y=5))
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(width=x.width), stat="identity", position="stack")
p <- p + facet_grid(x.group~., scales="free_x")
p
```

Plot is added to visualise wanted result. x.try.1 is my failed attempt.

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation of what "x.wanted" is

Comment: Ok. Now updated.

Comment: *"I thought `shift` was the way, but gives wrong result"* doesn't tell us much. Please reduce the data to the minimum to show why shift is wrong, and post the output of using shift. Related: dnlbrky's answer [Use a value from the previous row in an R data.table calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084650/202229) where he/she shows you how to define `rowShift(B,-1)` . Please try that, I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I thought rowShift was a solution for data.table pre 1.9.6. The accepted solution in your link was the one I started from.

Comment: can you show how did you get 9 in row 3? i think you might be looking for `Reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to locate the *midpoints* of the bars. This can be achieved by using the `cumsum()` function (plus `shift()`):

```
dt[, x.mid := cumsum(shift(x.width, fill = 0) + x.sep) + x.width/2, by = x.group][]
```

> ```
>    x.group x.width x.sep x.wanted x.try.1 x.mid
> 1:       1       2     0        1       1     1
> 2:       1       4     1        5       4     5
> 3:       1       2     1        9       4     9
> 4:       1       6     1       14       5    14
> 5:       2       4     0        2       2     2
> 6:       2       2     1        6       4     6
> 7:       2       4     1       10       4    10
> 8:       2       6     1       16       6    16
> 9:       2       2     1       21       5    21
> ```

The computed values of `x.mid` are in line with OP's `x.wanted`.

---

Another approach is to plot rectangles instead of bars. This will use the left and right cornerpoints on the x-axis which makes the computation more straightforward, IMHO:

```
dt[, x.min := cumsum(shift(x.width, fill = 0) + x.sep), by = x.group]

ggplot(dt, aes(xmin = x.min, xmax = x.min + x.width, ymin = 0, ymax = 5)) +
  geom_rect() +
  facet_grid(x.group ~ .)
```

This will create the same chart as shown in OP's question.