# Continuous multiplication same column previous value

Tags: r, math, multiple-columns, shift, continuations

I have a problem.
I have the following data frame.

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 100 |
| 1.00499 | NA |
| 1.00813 | NA |
| 0.99203 | NA |

Two columns. In the second column, apart from the starting value, there are only NAs. I want to fill the first NA of the 2nd column by multiplying the 1st value from column 2 with the 2nd value from column 1 (100* 1.00499). The 3rd value of column 2 should be the product of the 2nd new created value in column 2 and the 3rd value in column 1 and so on. So that at the end the NAs are replaced by values.

These two sources have helped me understand how to refer to different rows. But in both cases a new column is created.I don't want that. I want to fill the already existing column 2.

[Use a value from the previous row in an R data.table calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689424/use-a-value-from-the-previous-row-in-an-r-data-table-calculation)

https://statisticsglobe.com/use-previous-row-of-data-table-in-r

Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much in advance.

Sample code

```
library(quantmod)
data.N225<-getSymbols("^N225",from="1965-01-01", to="2022-03-30", auto.assign=FALSE, src='yahoo') 
data.N225[c(1:3, nrow(data.N225)),]

data.N225<- na.omit(data.N225)
N225 <- data.N225[,6]


N225$DiskreteRendite= Delt(N225$N225.Adjusted)
N225[c(1:3,nrow(N225)),]

options(digits=5)
N225.diskret <- N225[,3]
N225.diskret[c(1:3,nrow(N225.diskret)),]

N225$diskretplus1 <- N225$DiskreteRendite+1
N225[c(1:3,nrow(N225)),]

library(dplyr)
N225$normiert <-"Value"
N225$normiert[1,] <-100
N225[c(1:3,nrow(N225)),]

N225.new <- N225[,4:5]
N225.new[c(1:3,nrow(N225.new)),]
```

Here is the code to create the data frame in R studio.

```
a <- c(NA, 1.0050,1.0081, 1.0095, 1.0016,0.9947)
b <- c(100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c<- data.frame(ONE = a, TWO=b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cumprod` for cummulative product

```
transform(
    df,
    TWO = cumprod(c(na.omit(TWO),na.omit(ONE)))
)
```

which yields

```
     ONE      TWO
1     NA 100.0000
2 1.0050 100.5000
3 1.0081 101.3140
4 1.0095 102.2765
5 1.0016 102.4402
6 0.9947 101.8972
```

---

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ONE = c(NA, 1.005, 1.0081, 1.0095, 1.0016, 0.9947
), TWO = c(100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about (gasp) a **for loop**?

(I'll use `dat` instead of `c` for your dataframe to avoid confusion with function `c()`).

```r
for (row in 2:nrow(dat)) {
        if (!is.na(dat$TWO[row-1])) {
                dat$TWO[row] <- dat$ONE[row] * dat$TWO[row-1]
        }
}
```

This means:
For each row from the second to the end, if the `TWO` in the previous row is not a missing value, calculate the `TWO` in this row by multiplying `ONE` in the current row and `TWO` from the previous row.

Output:

```r
#>      ONE      TWO
#> 1     NA 100.0000
#> 2 1.0050 100.5000
#> 3 1.0081 101.3140
#> 4 1.0095 102.2765
#> 5 1.0016 102.4402
#> 6 0.9947 101.8972
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I'd love to read a `dplyr` solution!

Comment: Hi Andrea, on the small data frame I posted you solution works! Actually i have data about 14000 rows to which this calculation must be applied. If I use it there I get the error "Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : replacement has length zero". Do you have an idea why? I updated my question above. There you can find my complete code.