# Calculate the difference if the subsequent string in a column is different

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I want to calculate the difference if the subsequent string in a column is different. Example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(role = c("Mother", "Mother", "Mother", "Mother", "Child", "Mother", "Mother", "Child"),
                 bmi = c(22, 19, 21, 20, 17, 23, 22, 16))
```

For this data, if the role has switched (e.g., `Mother` -> `Child` or `Child` -> `Mother`), we calculate the difference. The expected output:

```
   role bmi diff
 Mother  22  NA
 Mother  19  NA
 Mother  21  NA
 Mother  20  NA
 Child   17  3
 Mother  23  -6
 Mother  22  NA
 Child   16  6
```

How do I do this?

The suggested link [Use a value from the previous row in an R data.table calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689424/use-a-value-from-the-previous-row-in-an-r-data-table-calculation) doesn't have the matching process.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I want to match strings not numbers. Also I don't see how they match the values

Comment: E.g. using `dplyr`: `mutate(df, diff = ifelse(role != lag(role), lag(bmi) - bmi, NA))`